# TRIM t-sql parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @Text1 varchar(10) = ' ltrim'
DECLARE @Text2 varchar(10) = 'rtrim '
DECLARE @Text3 varchar(10) = ' ltrimrtrim '

INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (LTRIM(RTRIM(@text1)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@text2)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@text3)))`
```

I get a red squiggly line under

```
"LTRIM(RTRIM(@text1))"
```

part (tooltip msg: ltrim fx requires 1 argument).

What am I doing wrong? Please kindly advise.

Thank you

Comment: can you please show the table structure that you are trying to insert into?

Comment: Mouse over the red squiggly line. What does the tooltip say? Are you on a case sensitive collation? If so it will complain `@Text1` <> `@text1`

Comment: Edited the initial comment. I will try bluefeet's sln. thank you for replies.

Comment: That error message about LTRIM requiring 1 argument would indicate messed up brackets to me. Have you posted the exact code that gives the error?

Comment: ROFL...you are right!!!!!!!!, I was missing brackets. facepalm/punch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a `table` called `table`? If so, then try square brackets around the table name `[table]` as table is a reserved word.

You code below is working:

```
DECLARE @Text1 varchar(10) = ' ltrim'
DECLARE @Text2 varchar(10) = 'rtrim '
DECLARE @Text3 varchar(20) = ' ltrimrtrim '

select LTRIM(RTRIM(@text1)) col1, 
  LTRIM(RTRIM(@text2)) col2, 
  LTRIM(RTRIM(@text3)) col3
into #temp

select *
from #temp
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9392)

Comment: Thanks bluefeed for your code. Turns out I was missing brackets. hehe Just curious, is there any performance diff b/w what I posted and what you posted? Thanks (also that site is pretty cool).

Comment: No there is no difference. I jus loaded the data into a temp table. :)